# Japanese Hiragana Mode in Search field

Tags: javascript, jquery, lang

Folks,

I have a search field on my webpage and this webpage is used in Japanese mode too; the issue is when we type in Hiragana mode of Japanese language while using search box, it types in Japanese numbers; i am replacing them to english digits but while we are in Hiragana input mode we need to press TWO times the enter key to fire the search.

How can we implement something in Javascript or jQuery so that pressing Enter only once it fires the search instead of two times??

### Code:

```
function cleanup(elem) {
    elem.value = elem.value.replace(/[１２３４５６７８９０]/g, function (m) {
        return String.fromCharCode(m.charCodeAt(0) - 65248)
    });
}
```

Comment: Since Enter is used to confirm the IME input I don't think there's a general way to do this nor that you should be doing this. Think about how it typically works on all pages for Japanese users and stick to that; don't surprise your users with custom behavior.

Comment: Where can i find it in IME documentation so that i can show it to users as they are asking for it.. i know it is a default behaviour which is used to confirm IME but i need the links for it.. ;)

Comment: There is no "the IME documentation" since there's more than one IME, working differently on different platforms. That why there's no general way this can work everywhere.